# How can i solve this problem about averages?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

The average (arithmetic mean) bowling score of $n$ bowlers is $160$. The average of these $n$ scores together with a score of $170$ is $161$. What is the number of bowlers, $n$?

I tried this:

$$X'*n = 160*n = x_1 + \dots + x_n$$

$$X'*n = 161*n = x_1 + \dots + x_n + 170$$

$$\frac{161*n}{160*n} = \frac{x_1 + \dots + x_n + 170}{x_1 + \dots + x_n}$$

Comment: @Belgi, I have edited the original post.

Comment: While writing down an equation is a good way to solve the problem, one can do it in an algebra-free way. Suppose that the new bowler had bowled $160$. Then the average wouldn't change. But she bowled $170$, which gave everybody, including herself, $1$ extra point on average. Thus, *including* the new bowler, there must be $10$ people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the total score of the $n$ bowlers is $S$, then the average is

$$A = \frac{S}{n} = 160\,,\quad (1)  $$

The second statement is telling you that the average of these $n$ scores adding to them the score (170) of another player (you will have $n+1$ bowlers) is 161. That translates to

$$ 161 = \frac{ S+170 }{n+1}\,,\quad (2) \,. $$

Now, solve the two equations to get $n$. Solution $(n=9)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  what is the total score of the original $n$ bowlers?  If you add another bowler who hits $170$, what is the total?  How many bowlers are there now?

Comment: I can't understand.

Comment: The definition of the average score is the total score divided by the number of bowlers.

Comment: I know what average is.

Comment: @guru:  Then what don't you understand?  The total score is $160n$.  Having done that, try the next two.

Comment: What i did is correct? See the original post again please.

Comment: @guru:  To help the reader you should define the variables:  "Let x1,x2,...xn be the original scores.  Let X' be" what?  In your first line, clearly 161*n does not equal 160*n.  It would be easier to let $N$ be the total of the original scores, instead of x1+x2+...xn.  The numerator should be $161(n+1)$ as there are now $n+1$ scores, but after that fix your second line is correct.